# Detect if UIbuttons overlap

Tags: ios

I have two UIButtons on my view, and I am trying to detect if the two overlap, in oder to do:

if (overlap)
move the second button

I have tried this:

```
if (BluetoothDeviceButton.X1 < btn.X2 && BluetoothDeviceButton.X2 > btn.X1 &&
    BluetoothDeviceButton.Y1 < btn.Y2 && BluetoothDeviceButton.Y2 > btn.Y1){

 }
```

I can't really get what I should put instead of X1, X2, etc. And I don't really know if this method is going to work at all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`CGRectIntersectsRect(CGRect rect1, CGRect rect2)` will tell you if their frames overlap.

```
if (CGRectIntersectsRect(btn.frame, BluetoothDeviceButton.frame)) {
   ...
}
```

Comment: This is the best technique to detect the overlap, there is no need to get into texting Xs and Ys ;).

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `BluetoothDeviceButton.frame.origin.x` or `BluetoothDeviceButton.center.x`.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly make sure they are in the same view. If not, then get their frames using `convertRectToView`, or `converRectFromView`. Then use the `CGRectContainsPoint` of the `CGGeometry` class and check if any corner of one button lies in the frame of the other button.

PS. your corners will be:

```
CGFloat x1 = button1.frame.origin.x;
CGFloat y1 = button1.frame.origin.y;
CGFloat x2 = button1.frame.origin.x + button1.frame.size.width;
CGFloat y2 = button1.frame.origin.y + button1.frame.size.height;
```

Your corners will be:

```
CGPoint topLeft = CGPointMake(x1,y1);
CGPoint topRight = CGPointMake(x2,y1);
CGPoint bottomLeft = CGPointMake(x1,y2);
CGPoint bottomRight = CGPointMake(x2,y2);
```

This is just one possible solution. This is just to help understand geometry.

But the simplest solution would be using `CGRectIntersectsRect (button1.frame, button2.frame);`

Answer (score 0):

Use BluetoothDeviceButton.frame.origin.x. Frame property contain also size.